# Infinite Looping in a Qt Widget Project

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I am making something in a Qt Widget Project, coded in C++. Because of what I need to do, I need infinite looping, and after doing my research, I realized that infinite looping in an object's event doesn't work, and instead, I need to use a some threading..

1. I decided to use QTimer, but am thinking about using QThread. Which one should I use?
2. This is my QTimer code, which doesn't seem to work:

   ```
   Clock_Application::Clock_Application(QWidget *parent) :
       QMainWindow(parent),
       ui(new Ui::Clock_Application)
   {
       ui->setupUi(this);
       QTimer *timer_Stopwatch = new QTimer(this);
       connect(timer_Stopwatch, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer_Start()));
       timer_Stopwatch->start(1000);
   }
   ```

**Edit: a simple fix to this solution is using the `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` function, after every iteration of the loop, as that allows the widget application to process necessary events. This is a quick fix however, and using the QTimer library is a better way to fix it.**

Comment: What about it isn't working? What is the goal? We need more details.

Comment: The program will not respond, because infinite looping in an object's event does not work.

Comment: I mean what *about the code you posted* doesn't work?

Comment: I think I'm using the QTimer wrong, as it is not changing the result (still unresponsive) as I thought it would..

Comment: We're not mind readers. Post more code and describe what "as I thought it would" means.

Comment: "As I thought it would" would mean that it would AT LEAST BE RESPONSIVE.

Comment: Your question is unclear without more significant code, but a couple of hints: If your code is in an infinite loop, Qt's event system won't get the chance to process any events. The timer won't really solve anything. Performing your processing in a thread would be an option. A quick fix would be to manually call [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) at the end of each loop.

Comment: I do not understand what is so unclear. The only thing that matters is that the program is becoming unresponsive due to an infinite loop. If you need to see that then here: `while (true) {}`. Anyway, thanks for the help, I'm going to test it.

Comment: Most applications do not need infinite loops, so most probably there is a much better alternative than infinite loop with processEvents().

Comment: @Roku +1 Couldn't agree more. The OP should really consider that, but without more info it's difficult to suggest anything specific. As I said, using processEvents is simply a quick fix.

Comment: Well, I am making a timer, and I want it to go up until I press the pause button, so pretty much it's infinite. If there are any alternatives, I'd gladly listen to them.

Comment: It is not infinitive. Just use QTimer. When your timer starts, start the QTimer. In the timeout event do whatever you want, for example print the time. When the pause button is pressed, stop the QTimer. You would have got an answer much faster, if you had shown your infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggest yourself, performing your processing in a separate thread would be an option and I would surely look into doing that. I don't think that the QTimer as you show it will help.

A quick fix however would be to manually call [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) at the end of each loop. This will make sure that all the pending events get processed by Qt, keeping your UI responsive.

Comment: Thanks, after doing this, my program worked! Unfortunately though, the program is relatively laggy when I try to move the screen around. I'm a perfectionist as you may understand, so are there any ways to make it more smooth?

Comment: It is most likely laggy because even 1 loop takes a significant amount of time. As I said, it's just a quick fix. If there is a significant amount of processing happening, you might indeed want to do it in a separate thread.

Answer (score -1):

Your timer is not working because it only exists in the constructor. You should declare it out the constructor in the header file as private for example.

Comment: This is just wrong. Im no qt expert, but it doesnt matter where to instantiate an object to use it.